# How to get a line-plot of all the rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

It's not my data but we can use it as an example:

```
Name     1st   2nd   3rd   4th   5th  6th  7th   
Gregg     0    0.6   1     0.2   0    0.5    1  
Mike     0.4    1    0.6   0     0    0      0 
Susane    1     0    0     0     1    0.3    0 
Marcel    0     1    0.75  0.25  0    0      0
```

I would like to get a line-plot of every row of this data. How can I do it efficiently for a big data set?

For every row, the maximum is always `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by plot?

Comment: Maybe `matplot(t(dat[-1,]))`? It's unclear what kind of data structure you have and what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't mention what kind of plot you want, here are two examples (with the `ggplot2` package):

```
# reading the data
df <- read.table(text = "Name     first   second   third   fourth   fifth  sixth  seventh   
Gregg     0    0.6   1     0.2   0    0.5    1  
Mike     0.4    1    0.6   0     0    0      0 
Susane    1     0    0     0     1    0.3    0 
Marcel    0     1    0.75  0.25  0    0      0", header = TRUE)

# transforming the data to long format
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id = "Name")

# creating a barplot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```
# creating a line plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x = as.numeric(variable), y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~ Name)
```

[image]

Comment: I need a lineplot. Thanks!